# Alamofire 5 Migration

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm having problems of migrating this code to Alamofire 5:

```
init(plugins: [PluginType] = []) {
    let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
        "test.com.ph": .pinCertificates(
            certificates: ServerTrustPolicy.certificates(),
            validateCertificateChain: true,
            validateHost: true
        )
    ]
    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 120 // default is 60.
    let manager = Manager(
        configuration: configuration,
        serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
    )

    super.init(manager: manager, plugins: plugins)
}
```

I have modified my code same but I don't know how to initialize the session manager:

```
let pinEvaluator = PinnedCertificatesTrustEvaluator(certificates: Bundle.main.af.certificates,
                                                    acceptSelfSignedCertificates: true,
                                                    performDefaultValidation: true,
                                                    validateHost: true)

let trustManager = ServerTrustManager.init(evaluators: ["test.com.ph": pinEvaluator])

let sessionManager = Session.init(configuration: .default, serverTrustManager: trustManager)

super.init(session: sessionManager,plugins: plugins)
```

[image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you describe your error and reproducible code? Are you using any library other than `Alamofire` for networking?

Comment: I am also using Moya. However whenever I switch to my prod environment upon logging in I was prompted this error? :'(

Comment: are you sure updating this host `test.com.ph` to production?

Answer (score 2):

As the error states, you made a request to a host you hadn't registered with your `ServerTrustEvaluating` value. That is, a request that wasn't to `test.com.ph`. You'll want to ensure you're making requests to the proper host, or that you've used the correct host for your certificate pinning.

If you expect to make requests to multiple hosts, you can disable this behavior by initializing the `ServerTrustManager` with the `allHostsMustBeEvaluated` property set to `false`.